# Seaborn Heatmap without lines between cells

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I´m trying to create a heatmap with seaborn with a transparent colormap since an image should be displayed in the background. The heatmap creation works fine so far, however some lines between the cells are still visible even though the linewidth of the heatmap is set to 0.0.

The code for the creation of the heatmap looks like the following:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(image, cmap="rocket_r", linewidths=0.0)
ax.collections[0].set_alpha(0.5)
```

Where `image` is 64x64 numpy array. The resulting heatmap looks like this:
[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sRoT.png) (sorry not enough repuation for embedding pictures)

The problem are the thin lines between the cells. Strangely they aren´t at every edge.

Anyone knows how to get rid of those lines?

Many Thanks

---

Update 1 (Complete working example):

```
image = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]])
ax = sns.heatmap(image, cmap="rocket_r", linewidths=0.0)
ax.collections[0].set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

Results is this heatmap:

[image: this heatmap]

Here you can see that there are thin lines between every column but there isn´t any line between the first and second row.

Comment: Can you create a small set of data with complete code?

Comment: @ScottBoston I´ve just added a working representative code sample, where you can see that some lines are created and others aren´t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines are the overlapping of semitransparent patches which cannot be perfectly aligned on the pixel grid.

#### alpha blending

An option is to not use transparency, but instead create opaque colors with alpha blending.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

def get_alpha_blend_cmap(cmap, alpha):
    cls = plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.linspace(0,1,256))
    cls = (1-alpha) + alpha*cls
    return ListedColormap(cls)

image = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]])
ax = sns.heatmap(image, cmap=get_alpha_blend_cmap("rocket_r", 0.5), linewidths=0.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

An obvious advantage of this is that the colorbar has the same colors as the heatmap.

#### increase dpi

If the above is not an option you may increase the dpi when saving.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

image = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]])
ax = sns.heatmap(image, cmap="rocket_r", linewidths=0.0, edgecolor="none", alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=1000)
```

[image]

This does of course not have any effect on the figure shown on screen though.

#### imshow

Finally, consider not using seaborn here, but instead a matplotlib `imshow` plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")
plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "white"
import numpy as np

image = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]])
im = plt.imshow(image, cmap="rocket_r", alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.gca().set(xticks=(range(image.shape[1])),yticks=(range(image.shape[0])))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It removes the undesired lines as wished. However I run into the next problem. As stated in the initial question I´m trying to show an image in the background (.png with help of `plt.imshow()`). Therefore the heatmap needs to be transparent. However with opaque colors the background isn´t visible. I´ve "fixed" this by moving the image to the foreground and giving it an alpha value. But then the colormap doesn´t match the true colors anymore. Is it possible to modify the colorbar in the same way? Or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I added two other options to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Both solutions work just fine for me. However I´m gonna stick with seaborn (2nd solution) as the appearance is just a little bit cleaner.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaner"? The whole problem of unclean edges goes away in the last solution?!

Comment: The problem I had with the matplotlib solution were the horizontal lines in the colormap. I´ve now managed to remove them.
My final solution looks like this:
1. Plot heatmap with first option and add colormap according to blended colors
2.Clear axis of figure
3. Plot heatmap with option 3 but not creating the heatmap
Following this procedure results inthe exact output I aimed for.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this problem. I need to upload the plot to overleaf, so I do not like the dpi solutions. Here is what I came up with, based on the solution of OP:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

image = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]])
ax = sns.heatmap(image, cmap="rocket_r", linewidths=0.1)
colors = ax.collections[0].get_facecolors()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolors(colors)
plt.imshow()
```

The idea is to create a thin edge around each cell with the cell's facecolor. This removes the lines without changing the original cell colors.